# How to calculate kslice_b2 and kslice_b1 in wannierization?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, spin-orbit-coupling, wannier90

How is  reduced coordinates calculated in wannier90? examples 17- 18 , 29

Comment: Which examples? Do you mean examples from the official [Wannier90 tutorials](https://github.com/wannier-developers/wannier90/raw/v3.1.0/doc/compiled_docs/tutorial.pdf)?

Comment: yes, example from tutorial. If you know details please explain thanks